# Is it possible to put and implement a segue and pass data for a custom button shown after sliding a UITableViewCell?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I am new to iOS development and currently making a sleep tracker application. I want to know if it is possible to put or set up a segue and pass data in one of the buttons that is shown to user after swiping a `UITableViewCell` like in this screenshot

[image: UITableViewSwipe]

For reference, here is what I did to the buttons. It works for `UIAlertView` and changing of `ViewControllers`, but I don't know if I can apply segues here to pass data from one `ViewController` to another.

```
//tableview swipe action iOS8
-(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewRowAction *delete = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Delete" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
        {
            UIAlertView *confirmDelete = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete Sleep Record" message:@"Do you want to delete this entry?\n\nWARNING: This action cannot be undone." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Delete", nil];
            [confirmDelete show];
        }];
    delete.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UITableViewRowAction *edit = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@" Edit " handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
        {
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            ViewController *evc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"edit"];
            [evc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
            [self presentViewController:evc animated:YES completion:nil];
        }];
    edit.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.188 green:0.514 blue:0.984 alpha:1];

    return @[delete, edit]; //array with all the buttons you want. 1,2,3, etc...
}
```

If it is possible, how can I do it programmatically or through the XIB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have u tried

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"idSegue" sender:self];
```

in your delete and edit action handler.

Then implement prepareForSegue

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"idSegue"])
    {
        BViewController *BViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        BViewController.myarray = myarray; // access data and methods of BViewController here using its object
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.. Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: I will try later and will come back to see if it worked. But thanks for the quick response. :)

Comment: It throws an exception: "No segue with identifier 'editSegue'" even if I did put the code you are suggesting.

Comment: It now works. I just forgot to drag the `ViewController` to another one to establish a self `segue`. Thanks again.